# File.Exist or GetUserStoreForApplication.FileExist Does Not Work Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, file-io

I tried the following codes but none work. Silverlight 4.

```
if (!(File.Exists(@"C:\sybase\ini\sql.ini")))
{
    Log("Not able to find ini file");
    return false;
}

or

using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!(store.FileExists(@"c:\sybase\ini\sql.ini")))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist ");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is related to permissions.

Do any one have any idea how to read a file or check if a file exist in silverlight 4 application ?

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Silverlight 5 and check the option "Required elevated trust when running in-browser" in project properties.